# Views filter count

Tags: views

I'm trying to set up a block that will allow me to show 6 items in it, 2 that are checked yes and 4 that are checked no.  They are sorted by date so I have a pager set up to take the first 6 values.  What I would like is if for example the first 5 items are checked no and the next two are checked yes, then my block should show the first 4 no items and the first two yes items.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create one block.

Then for the same view create an attachment and add it to the block (after).

Set the pager for the block to display specified number of items : 2 , and set the sort to checked yes and then by date.

Set the pager for the attachment to display specified number of items : 4 , and set offset to 2. Set the sort to not checked yes and then by date.

To swap the order around set the attachment to attach before the block.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done by simple view as per my knowledge. You need to change the output of view's `$result` array in [hook_views_pre_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)

Comment: Thanks Himanshu - Or I guess I could also create two blocks

Comment: Yep, that would be better solution